# Visual Studio: Share Code between ASP and C# project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm developing an application which contains two segments:

1. a C# form application
2. a ASP.NET web form application.

During development of these two segments(projects), many functions are same and developing them in two different projects is not reasonable since the development time is wasted this way.
So i want to know are there any method to share code/classes which is used in both projects or not? Something like creating projects in same solution or any other methods which does not make problems during publishing of application on Web or in .exe format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1 :** if you want to expose your API functionality to the multiple applications You can create `WebServices` and expose them via wsdl file.so that you can consume those services from any application.

Try This [Web Services](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308359)

**Solution 2:**

You can create a `ClassLibrary` Project which generates `.dll` files which can be used from any other application to access the API functions.

Follow the below steps to create the Library Project which contains common functions (API):

**Step1 :**  Create a New `ClassLibrary` Project with name `MyLibraryProject`(you can assign any name) as shown below:

[image]

**Step2 :** Create the Library functions which are commonly used as below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyLibraryProject
{
    public class MathLibraryClass
    {
        public int num1 { get; set; }
        public int num2 { get; set; }
        public int Sum(int n1,int n2)
        {
            num1 = n1;
            num2 = n2;
            return num1 + num2;
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 3:** Now `build` the project to get the `MyLibraryProject.dll` file in your project folder.

**Step 4:** Now goto your project folder which contains dll files. the path is either deubug folder or Release folder based on your `Build Output Path`.

**Note :** I assume your Build POutput Path is `Release` Folder

**Step 5:** Now Goto Release Folder path :

`ProjectFolder->MyLibraryProject->MyLibraryProject->bin->Release`

**Step 6:** Now the folder contains dll file shown as below:

[image]

**Step 7:** Now dll file is generated successfully so you can add this dll file as reference to any of your project to consume those common api functions.

**Step 8** Now create a project (here as an example i'm creating console application) which consumes the common functions generated in  dll.

**Step 9:** Now add your dll file as reference by following steps:

Right Click on your newly created project.
Select `References`
Select `Add Reference...`

Select the Browse option from Reference Manager window as shown below:

[image]
Now Select the required dll as shown below:

[image]

**Step 10:** Now Add the library project namespace in your project by `using` statement

```
using MyLibraryProject;
```

**Step 11:** Now Write the following code in your console Application to utilize the library functions

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using MyLibraryProject;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MathLibraryClass myclass = new MathLibraryClass();
            int sum = myclass.Sum(12, 4);
            Console.WriteLine("sum is {0}", sum);
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 12:** Now you can see the below Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes - simply put the common code into a class library (dll). This is exactly what class libraries are for - for sharing code between projects.

Just make sure you target the class library to a .Net framework that is compatible with both the forms project and the ASP.NET one.

Comment: And place that library (dll) on the Bin directory of your asp.net application

Comment: @Aristos Just referencing it from the ASP.NET application should ensure that happens.